# how to create LXC container using busybox template for ARM architecture

Tags: linux, arm, lxc, busybox

I don't know much about lxc, recently started working on it a few days back.

I tried creating a Linux container on linux 14.04LTS via command:

```
lxc-create -t /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-busybox -n OpenWrt
```

And it ran fine there via lxc-start command.

I then **tar** it to **OpenWrt.tar.gz** and **copy** it on a Compex **board** running LEDE OS(**ARM architecture**) to directory **/srv/lxc/** where I **untar** it to get **/srv/lxc/OpenWrt** directory. Then when I tried to **run the container** via command:
`lxc-start -F -n OpenWrt`, I got the following error:

```
  lxc-start 20160210174618.933 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:instantiate_veth:2618 - failed to create veth pair (vethAPIAY5 and vethWJLSXO): Operation not supported
      lxc-start 20160210174618.936 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_create_network:2962 - failed to create netdev
      lxc-start 20160210174618.936 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:lxc_spawn:1088 - Failed to create the network.
      lxc-start 20160210174618.936 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1346 - Failed to spawn container "OpenWrt".
      lxc-start 20160210174618.971 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - tools/lxc_start.c:main:366 - The container failed to start.
      lxc-start 20160210174618.971 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - tools/lxc_start.c:main:370 - Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

Then I just commented the network configuration(first 4 lines) in config file kept at /srv/lxc/OpenWrt/config file, as shown below:

```
#lxc.network.type = veth
#lxc.network.flags = up
#lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
#lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:1d:e5:8c
lxc.rootfs = /srv/lxc/OpenWrt/rootfs
lxc.haltsignal = SIGUSR1
lxc.utsname = OpenWrt
lxc.tty = 1
lxc.pts = 1
lxc.cap.drop = sys_module mac_admin mac_override sys_time

# When using LXC with apparmor, uncomment the next line to run unconfined:
#lxc.aa_profile = unconfined
lxc.mount.entry = /lib lib none ro,bind 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /usr/lib usr/lib none ro,bind 0 0
#lxc.mount.entry = /sys/kernel/security sys/kernel/security none ro,bind,optional 0 0
lxc.mount.auto = proc:mixed sys
```

and run the container again via command:

```
lxc-start -n OpenWrt -l trace -o logfile.log
```

and got the **format error** this time as shown in logs below:

```
lxc-start 20160210181025.855 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:start:1431 - Exec format error - Failed to exec "/sbin/init".
      lxc-start 20160210181025.855 ERROR    lxc_sync - sync.c:__sync_wait:57 - An error occurred in another process (expected sequence number 5)
      lxc-start 20160210181025.856 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1346 - Failed to spawn container "OpenWrt".
      lxc-start 20160210181025.859 ERROR    lxc_cgfs - cgroups/cgfs.c:cgroup_rmdir:209 - Device or resource busy - cgroup_rmdir: failed to delete /sys/fs/cgroup/lxc/OpenWrt-2
      lxc-start 20160210181025.921 WARN     lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_rsp_recv:172 - Command get_cgroup failed to receive response: Connection reset by peer.
      lxc-start 20160210181030.927 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - tools/lxc_start.c:main:366 - The container failed to start.
      lxc-start 20160210181030.930 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - tools/lxc_start.c:main:368 - To get more details, run the container in foreground mode.
      lxc-start 20160210181030.936 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - tools/lxc_start.c:main:370 - Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

What I understood is that **I was trying to run a x86 binary on an ARM board that's why I got this error. Now I am** **trying to create an ARM compatible container on linux 14.04 machine so that it can run on that ARM Compex board running LEDE OS**. I am searching for options to specify the desired architecture in `lxc-create` command like to create ARM ubuntu lxc conatiner, I found a command ie:

```
lxc-create -n armubuntu -t ubuntu -- -a armhf -r precise
```

But when I tried to create a busybox container via following command:

```
lxc-create -n myOpenWrt -t busybox -- -a armhf
```

I got the invalid option error as:

```
getopt: invalid option -- 'a'
lxc-busybox -h|--help -p|--path=<path> -s|--ssh={dropbear,openssh}
```

Now I am searching over net for any such similar command to create the desired busybox container for ARM architecture or any container of small size(actually the created ubuntu ARM container was of size 426 MB, cannot be copied/tested on the board).

Someone please suggest something.

Thanks